# How do you switch from 1 button to another in Android?

Tags: android

Hey all, so I have a start and a stop button. What I would like to happen is once the start button is clicked, it disappears and the stop button shows up right in the spot of the start button so that the stop button is able to be clicked. Is this done by switch statements?

```
//Start Button
btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
   }
});

//Stop Button
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with eclipse...

Comment: @Mayra what are you talking about? This is definitely for android eclipse

Comment: @dtmilano i need 2 for a countdowntimer. (Start/Reset, Stop)

Comment: Eclipse is a text editor.  It does not in any way affect the running the Android code.  You could write the code in NotePad, compile it on the command line and it would do the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [setVisibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) with the two buttons adjacent in your layout:

```
//Start Button
btnstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            btnstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
});

//Stop Button
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            btnstop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnstart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, it worked just the way i wanted it to. can't believe i didnt think of that